# How to upgrade ubuntu12.10 to 13.04 in 30 minutes?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I tried to upgrade my ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04,It works correctly.But so slow.Is there any way for faster upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once done, you would do

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

When the window opens, just click on upgrade, and just follow the instructions.